# change element based on time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change this element based on time: text

I found this snippet, but what do I change/add so that it effects the h1?

```
var myDate = new Date();  

/* hour is before noon */ 
if ( myDate.getHours() < 12 ) {
    document.write("Good Morning!"); 
}

/* Hour is from noon to 5pm (actually to 5:59 pm) */
else if ( myDate.getHours() >= 12 && myDate.getHours() <= 17 ) {
    document.write("Good Afternoon!");
}

/* the hour is after 5pm, so it is between 6pm and midnight */
else if ( myDate.getHours() > 17 && myDate.getHours() <= 24 ) { 
    document.write("Good Evening!"); 
}

/* the hour is not between 0 and 24, so something is wrong */
else {
    document.write("I'm not sure what time it is!"); 
}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: I failed to find any element....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [JQuery](https://jquery.com/):

```
var myDate = new Date();
var text = "";

/* hour is before noon */
if ( myDate.getHours() < 12 )  {
   text = "Good Morning!";
}

/* Hour is from noon to 5pm (actually to 5:59 pm) */
else if ( myDate.getHours() >= 12 && myDate.getHours() <= 17 ) {
   text = "Good Afternoon!";
}

/* the hour is after 5pm, so it is between 6pm and midnight */
else if ( myDate.getHours() > 17 && myDate.getHours() <= 24 ) {
   text = "Good Evening!"; 
}

/* the hour is not between 0 and 24, so something is wrong */ 
else { 
   text = "I'm not sure what time it is!";
}

$("h1").text(text);
```

Without JQuery, the last line would instead be:

```
var h1s = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
for(var i = 0; i < h1s.length; i ++) {
    h1s[i].innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have one h1 tag on your page, and you can give 'id' attribute and change the contents according to the current time: Below code may help you

```js
var myDate = new Date();   /* hour is before noon */ if ( 
myDate.getHours() < 12 )  { 
  document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML ="Good Morning!"; } 
else if ( myDate.getHours() >= 12 && myDate.getHours() <= 17 ) 
 {     document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML ="Good Afternoon!"; } 
else if ( myDate.getHours() > 17 && myDate.getHours() <= 24 )
  {     document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML= "Good Evening!"; } 
 else 
  {     document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML="I'm not sure what time it is!"; }
```

```html
<h1 id="greeting"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `document.write(...)` to `document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].write(...)`

This would write to the first `h1` tag in your webpage